# MAX and MIN stock with time

Tags: c

suppose we could access today's stock prices as a list, where:
The indices are the time in minutes past trade opening time, which was 9:30am local time.
The values are the price in dollars of Apple stock at that time.
So if the stock cost $500 at 10:30am, stock_prices_yesterday[60] = 500.

Write an efficient function that takes stock_prices_yesterday and returns the best and lowest prices.

Assumption:

- Prices changes in interval of minutes only .
- Trading last up to 11:30PM (total minutes : 120)
- `stock_prices_yesterday` is an array .

Example:

- stock_prices_yesterday is array with indices 0 to 119
- stock_prices_yesterday = [2,12,33,21,122.......up to 119 times]
- Should return 2 as min and 122 as maximum price at time : 9:30AM and 9:34AM )

Inputs:

```
2,12,33,21,122.......
```

Output:

```
2 122 9:30AM 9:34AM
```

i tried this
sorry i am completely new to programming....

```
int main(void) {
    int stock_prices_yesterday[120],i,j,small,large;
    for(i=0,i<120;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",stock_prices_yesterday[i]);
    }
    large=stock_prices_yesterday[0];
    small=stock_prices_yesterday[0];
    for(i=1;i<120;i++)
    {
        if(stock_prices_yesterday[i]>large)
            large=stock_prices_yesterday[i];
        if(stock_prices_yesterday[i]<small);
        small=stock_prices_yesterday[i];
    }
    printf("%d %d",small,large);
```

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: sorry i am completely new to programming....                                           int main(void) {
 int stock_prices_yesterday[120],i,j,small,large;
        for(i=0,i<120;i++)
{ scanf("%d",stock_prices_yesterday[i]);
}
large=stock_prices_yesterday[0];
small=stock_prices_yesterday[0];
 for(i=1;i<120;i++)
{
if(stock_prices_yesterday[i]>large)
large=stock_prices_yesterday[i];
if(stock_prices_yesterday[i]<small);
small=stock_prices_yesterday[i];}
printf("%d %d",small,large);

Comment: Can someone help me with this code

Comment: Yes, your instructor.

Comment: sorry i didn't knew..thanks for informing

Comment: You have an extra semi-colon after the last `if` statement.

Comment: "*Output: `... 9:30AM 9:34AM`*" Where does this come from? You do not seem to show your "real" code ...

Answer (score 0):

This

```
scanf("%d",stock_prices_yesterday[i]);
```

should make the compiler issue a warning, as it should be

```
scanf("%d", &stock_prices_yesterday[i]);
```

`scanf()` expects addresses to the variables it should scan into.